# pod install AFNetworking for osx produce "frameworks.sh: line 43: source: unbound variable" error

Tags: cocoapods, afnetworking

in **Podfile**:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
```

then -> pod install for an macosx xcodeproject, open workspace and build, it produce an error which like:

```
mkdir -p pathto-frameworks.sh: line 43: source: unbound variable
```

when I remove AFNetworking in my Podfile, everything goes fine.

> xcode version: xcode 10.12.1
>
> osX version : macOS catalina 10.15.1

please help!

Comment: after pod install: 3.2.1 of AFNetworking installed

Answer (score 0):

turned out to be my own problem, some xcode build settings conflict with pod settings, Fixed!